# prefix & postfix notation of some integer numbers

Tags: c++

I am having problem in understanding the output resulting from the following line:

```
 cout<<(a++) + (++a) + (a++);
```

It gives 18 for a=5 but I can't understand how? When I wrote separate output line like:

```
cout<<a++;
cout<<++a;
cout<<a++;
```

It gives the following output for a=5;

5 7 7.

> What can be the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points